# migrating aspx view to Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some problems to migrate my mvc aspx views to Razor view. What is right Razor syntax for following? thanks a lot.

```
<%
    Html.Repeater<BoardViewModel>(
        Model.Boards, 
        "post", 
        "post", 
        (board, css) =>{%>

    <div class= "<% =css%>"> 
        <div class="post_title"><h2><% = Html.ActionLink(board.Name, "GetById", "Board", new {id=board.Id}, null) %></h2></div> 
        <div class="post_body"> 
            <p><% =board.Description%></p> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   <%}); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simplify this to the following (or something like it) rather than having to worry about the delegates. Cleaner in my opinion.

```
@foreach(Board board in Model.Boards){
    <text>   
    <div class="post"> 

        <div class="post_title"><h2>@Html.ActionLink(board.Name, "GetById", "Board", new {id=board.Id}, null)</h2></div> 
        <div class="post_body"> 
            <p>@board.Description</p> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```